# Deriving `CanEqual` succeeds on function when it shouldn't

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm a beginner with Scala, but I'm wondering why the following compiles in Scala 3?

```
import scala.language.strictEquality

case class C(x: String => String) derives CanEqual
```

Shouldn't this fail because `CanEqual` is not defined on `String => String` and hence can't be derived?

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't.

Simply speaking, with `derives CanEqual` here you just give the compiler know that it's legal to use `==` or `!=` with instances of `C`. The compiler will add an instance of `CanEqual` for `C` itself.

The things are different with generic classes (type constructors), as `with CanEqual` derives `CanEqual` that requires presence of `CanEqual` instances for all type parameters. It's however a constraint that's a result of using this particular method of deriving instances. You can always provide it yourself and then even for generic classes you may not need `CanEqual` for type parameters. E.g. this seems to be working:

```scala
class C[T](t: T)
given CanEqual[C[_], C[_]] = CanEqual.derived
println(new C[Int](1) == new C[String]("1")) // false
```

As I said, it's just a green light for using `==` or `!=`, it doesn't construct/derive the comparison operation itself. `equals()` method is used, whatever is its implementation. So for your case it will use default case class `equals()` method and it will use reference comparison for function in `x`.

Worth noting that `scala.language.strictEquality` doesn't limit usage of `equals()`

More reading:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-multiversal-equality.html
https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/multiversal-equality.html
plus I find descriptions of this feature in "Programming in Scala" and "Programming Scala" new editions a bit easier to digest

Hope it helps a bit